# dropdown menu value doesn't change

Tags: flutter, dart

My dropdown menu works fine but when I've added the `navigator.push`, in the `setstate()` method it didn't change the value after selecting it. It did push the data though.

I need to push the data as well as the value of the dropdown menu to change. If there's a way to pass data to another **stateful class** depending on the choice of the dropdown menu.

Below is my full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

import '../widgets/My_wedgits.dart';

// shmalyh 3  LatLng(21.489191114466923, 39.24285294444855)
//shmalyh 1   LatLng( 21.490190928284374, 39.24029335794148)
//west 2   LatLng(21.489312801215913, 39.239637004938416)

//double lat = 21.48880614639443;
//double leng = 39.24159501940586;
 String dropdownvalue = "";

const List<String> gatelist = <String>[
  'NorthGate 1',
  'NorthGate 2',
  'WestGate 2'
];

class homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  //const homepage({super.key});
  double lat;
  double lan;

  homepage({Key? mykey, required this.lan, required this.lat})
      : super(key: mykey);

  @override
  State<homepage> createState() => _homepageState();
}

class _homepageState extends State<homepage> {
  DropdownButtonExample mydropdown = DropdownButtonExample();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 60,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text(
            'Wajeeh',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 28,
            ),
          ),
          elevation: 10,
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 105, 55),
          leading: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            child: Image.asset(
              'images/logo2.png',
              height: 30,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 70,
            ),
            Row(
              // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
              children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 250,
                    child: mydropdown,
                  ),
                )),
              ],
            ),

            const SizedBox(
              height: 45,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset('images/full.jpg'),
                    const Text(
                      'Total Parking',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      '33',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 105, 55)),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
                Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset('images/remain.jpg'),
                    const Text(
                      'Available Parking',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      "100",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 105, 55)),
                    ),
                  ],
                ))
              ],
            ),
            //here where the map should be
            const SizedBox(
              height: 70,
            ),

            Row(
              // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
              children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 355,
                    height: 315,
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        GoogleMap(
                          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                            target: LatLng(widget.lan, widget.lat),
                            zoom: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.star,
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 210, 23),
                            size: 40,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }

  // ignore: unused_element

}

class DropdownButtonExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropdownButtonExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<DropdownButtonExample> createState() => _DropdownButtonExampleState();

  /*Widget goodglemap() {
    return GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(lat, leng),
        zoom: 16,
      ),
    );
  }*/
}

class _DropdownButtonExampleState extends State<DropdownButtonExample> {
  double lat = 21.48880614639443;
  double leng = 39.24159501940586;

  String dropdownValue = gatelist.first;
  // ignore: avoid_print

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      hint: const Text("Choose a Gate"),
      isExpanded: true,
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_sharp),
      style: const TextStyle(color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 105, 55)),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 105, 55),
      ),
      onChanged: (String? value) {
        // This is called when the user selects an item.
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = value!;

//see if i can reach the other classs from here
          lat = 37.43296265331129;
          leng = -122.08832357078792;
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => homepage(lat: lat, lan: leng)));
        });
      },
      items: gatelist.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(
            value,
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );





  }





  Widget goodglemap() {
    return GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(lat, leng),
        zoom: 16,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: My problem is that when using  navigator.push , when I select from the menu it doesn't show the selected item,

Comment: the problem is that when using the navigator when I select from the dropdown menu it doesn't show the selected item, it's like it skips  "dropdown value = value!;"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your point. I was able to run your code, the drop-down value on the first page is selected and shown and I was able to navigate to the second screen (same screen layout), so the flow is working fine. but if your question is: how we can have the same drop-down value across multiple screens? then the answer is to use a state management technique with a library, like a provider or a cubit, all you have is to create a controller then all drop-down widgets should listen to this controller, wherever there is a change in the value, the controller will notify all the widgets. please note that the provider should be in a parent widget.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please add such information/questions in the comments and not as an answer itself.